# iPhone hide portion of image in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, image, uiscrollview

I am brand new to iPhone app development. I am trying to create an image reader using UIScrollView. I need to focus a portion of an image and hide the rest. Till now I am only able to focus required part of an image but have no clue how to hide the rest. I had a suggestion that, I need to add four views at top, bottom, left and right. I need to hide those as per requirement. But, I was able to go no where with the suggestion. Can you please tell me how can I implement the functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast I was successful in hiding part of an image. I used four views with background color and resized them according to the portion I need to display.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you really want to do. But if you think putting for views above I might suggest you use mask image for the same. Use alpha component.

Comment: Please allow me to explain myself. I have near about 10 images which I want to add to the scrollview using imageviews. Now, every image has some sections. I must show each section at a time. Once user slides, he will be able to see the next section. Once the user slides the last section of the image, the next image will appear. Till now, I not even have thought of the paging as I am in so much of pain with focus and hiding sections of an image. Hope this will help you to understand the scenario better.